# how can we implement a radio alarm in iphone?

Tags: iphone, alarm, internet-radio

I want to set alarm sound as selected radio streams for my app in iphone. 
  If any one knows  this please help me.

THANKS in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a local notification (alarm) that functions very similar to a "push notification". A dialog will be displayed, a static sound file can be played as well. If the user clicks "view" in the dialog, your app will open and you can start running code (i.e. load an audio stream).

So no, it's not really possible to load an audio stream from the network. You can KEEP streaming when you're in the background, but you can't START streaming.

You might be able to do it if your app was in the foreground, and the screen was just locked. But it wouldn't work if they left your app.